# Нужно ли обособлять сравнительный оборот "как Маша"?

Tags: сравнительный-оборот

Предложение с другого ресурса: ***Как Маша**(,) сейчас не танцуют.*

Ответов там много (**вопрос конкурсный)** и решения разные. Некоторые из них представляются верными, но все же **не до конца.** А какой ответ будет у вас?

Спасибо.

**[Как Маша, сейчас не танцуют. Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении? Почему?](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4359235-kak-masha-sejchas-ne-tancujut-nuzhna-li-zapjataja-v-etom-predlozhenii-pochemu.html#answer12365674)**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1. Предложение **простое**, стиль разговорный, но в то же время проблемное. Именно на таких примерах можно понять **уровень своих знаний.**
2. Интересно, что мнения пользователей разделились практически **поровну**. Но вот их доказательства говорят о том, что тема эта понимается не на должном уровне. Люди вспоминают **разные** правила, свободно меняют **порядок слов** в предложении. Но ведь для сравнительного оборота  (если это оборот) порядок слов очень важен и может **изменить** постановку знака.

Comment: Спасибо всем за внимание, ответы пока не будут рассматриваться.

Answer (score 2):

Понимаю, что тема мало кому интересна, но все-таки дам ответ.

1. Как отвечают на **[Большом вопросе](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4359235-kak-masha-sejchas-ne-tancujut-nuzhna-li-zapjataja-v-etom-predlozhenii-pochemu.html#answer12365674)**?   Да кто как, и все **неправильно.**  Что с нашим образованием, я не знаю.
2. **А вот как надо отвечать**.

Это классический **трехчастный оборот:** два лица (Маша и остальные) сравниваются через действие (танцевать). Задача имеет **два решения**, выбор зависит от **контекста**. При  обособлении подчёркивается  **сравнение**, а без обособления оборот является обстоятельством **образа действия**. При выборе решения учитывается **позиция** оборота.

**Так танцует Маша:**  https://yandex.ru/video/preview/3447466660449238592

(1) ***Как Маша** сейчас **не танцУют**, это  слишком просто.*

(2) *Это слишком просто. **Как МАша,** сейчас не танцуют.* **Актуализация** оборота в препозиции.

**А вот как надо танцевать**: https://vimeo.com/270031228

Comment: Тема сравнительных оборотов всегда интересна. Присоединяюсь к вашему ответу.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж за поддержку.  Согласна с вами, тема интересная и непростая.  Как раз собираюсь привести свои знания  в порядок по трем источникам: Розенталь, Кустова и Прияткина (она рассматривает трехчастные конструкции). Это разные уровни, тем любопытнее их соединить для полной ясности.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не нужно. Тем более, что это ни разу не сравнительный оборот)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151871/discussion-on-answer-by--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.